# ajaxSubmitButton: controller action not redirecting in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am using ajaxSubmitButton to POST data to my controller. That controller action then makes two insert statements in a transaction. All that is working just fine. What I want now is once the transaction is complete to be redirected to a new view but I can't get that to work.

When I click my button the transaction is processed but I remain on the same page. I have also tried using 'update' within the button and wrapping part of the page but none of the content updates. That is not ultimately what I am after though since I want to end up rendering a whole new view.

Here is what I have...

VIEW

```
 echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('submit',          
        array('/player/mark'), 
        array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'data' => array(...),
        ));
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function actionMark() 
{
        $connection = yii::app()->db;
        $transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
        try 
        {       
                $connection = yii::app()->db;
                $sql1 = "INSERT ...";
                $command=$connection->createCommand($sql1);
                ...
                $command->execute();


                $connection = yii::app()->db;
                $sql2 = "INSERT ...";
                $command=$connection->createCommand($sql2);
                ...
                $command->execute();

                $transaction->commit();
                $this->redirect(array('manage'));  // THIS IS NOT WORKING
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
                $transaction->rollBack();
                $this->refresh;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirect not working because you using ajax.

Try this code:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('submit',          
        array('/player/mark'), 
        array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'data' => array(...),
                'success' => 'js:function(){window.location="your_url"}', 
        ));
```

Replace *your_url* to url you want redirect to

Answer (score 1):

You should add window.location js after run success.
Reference to [this ajax submition button example](http://www.codexamples.com/90/chtml-ajaxsubmitbutton/):

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
    'Submit',
    '/post/ajax',
    array(
       'type'=>'POST',
       'dataType'=>'json',
       'success'=>'js:function(data){
           if(data.result==="success"){
              window.location="your_url"
           }else{
             $("#some-container").html(data.msg);
           }
       }',
    )
);
```

More [Yii examples](http://www.codexamples.com/)